# How to make retryable calls using RestClient

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I would like to enforce the Spring 6.1 `RestClient` to perform all http calls with a retry mechanism.
Ideally I would like to replicate this behavior achievable using `RestTemplate` and `spring-retry` `RetryTemplate`:

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = retryTemplate(retryProperties);

return new RestTemplate(requestFactory) {
  @Override
  public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(
      URI url,
      HttpMethod method,
      HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
      Class<T> responseType) {
    return retryTemplate.execute(
        context -> super.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType));
  }
};
```

For numerous reasons this approach is not valid in this case, but I'm looking for a solution to achieve something similar using `RestClient`

What would be alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: You could use org.springframework.retry:spring-retry provided functionality for the resttemplate OR since spring is prefering WebClient in newer versions you can switch the client implementation which will be a fluent client with a simple .retry() at sending the call. There can be different scenarios defied (retry on exception XY, amouint of retries, ...)

Answer (score 2):

You can usually set a RetryHandler/Strategy in the HttpClient. Depending on which client you use, the implementation may look different.

If you are using Apache Http Client 5, you can set a RetryStrategy in this way:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun clientHttpRequestFactory(): ClientHttpRequestFactory {
        val maxRetryAttempts = 3
        val delayInMillis = 300L
        val client = HttpClients.custom()
            // Will only retry on low level I/O exceptions or status codes 429, 503
            .setRetryStrategy(DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy(maxRetryAttempts, TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(delayInMillis)))
            .build()
        return HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client)
    }
    
    @Bean
    fun customRestClient(clientHttpRequestFactory: ClientHttpRequestFactory): RestClient {
        return RestClient.builder()
            .requestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory)
            .build()
    }
```

Be aware that the DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy will only retry low lewel ***IO exceptions*** or ***status code 429, 503***. If you need something specific, you could implement your own RetryStrategy.

**Alternatively**, you can also reuse your current RestTemplate and pass it to the RestClient Builder:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun customRestClient(customRetryRestTemplate: RestTemplate): RestClient {
        return RestClient
            .builder(customRetryRestTemplate)
            .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use spring-retry:

Add these dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then use @Retryable with your restClient with maxAttempts and delay, as so:

```
  @Retryable(maxAttempts = 10, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
  public void performRestCall() {
    restClient
        .post()
        .uri("YOUR_URI")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(YOUR_BODY)
        .exchange(
            (request, response) -> {
              if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
              
              return response.bodyTo(String.class);
            });
  }
```

Add this to your SpringApplication

```
@EnableRetry
```